# Magento csv import with same category name in 2 stores applies to 1 category

Tags: php, magento, csv, import

I have a magento store with a category structure I'll describe like this:

```
Root Category -> Sub Category
```

Assume I have 2 root categories, each assigned to a store, with the same category name in each:

```
Default Category -> Items
Spanish Category -> Items
```

I have 2 websites described like this:

```
website (website code) -> store (root category) -> store view (store code):

English Website (base) -> English (Default Category) -> US (en_us)
Spanish Website (es)   -> Spanish (Spanish Category) -> Columbia (es_co)
```

I have a csv import file like this: (truncated)

```
sku,           _store,  _type,   _category,  _product_websites, etc...
test_product,  en_us,  virtual,  Items,      base
{blank}     ,  es_co,  {blank},  Items,      es
```

This validates properly, creates 1 product split between both the english and spanish websites properly.  What doesn't work, is that it will only add it to the category in the Spanish store.  My assumption is that Magento would be smart enough to recognize that this product is being added to the store (en_us) and apply it to the subcategory of that store's root, especially since the key used for the category on product import is not unique.

The latest category created seems to win.  In this case, I had created Default Website->Items before I made Spanish Website->Items.  This becomes clear if I try to import a product to a single website in which there are two conflicting category names.

Assume this import:

```
sku,           _store,  _type,   _category,  _product_websites, etc...
test_product,  en_us,  virtual,  Items,      base
```

This will also add the product to the **Spanish Website->Items** Category

My question is, am I doing something wrong?  Am I missing a key element somewhere to avoid this?  Is this a known issue?  I can't find anything through google that points to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a great solution to this, but here is my workaround:

Basically, I prefix all the categories in the other stores that have the same name.

e.g.:

```
store1->category1
store2->es_category1
```

Do a large import with csv

Then rename those categories back.

Not great, but effective.  Hopefully that helps someone...

Cheers